# Adjust width of tinymce editor in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMce gem in my ruby on rails project and I'm trying to adjust the width of the editor. At the moment, the editor has 100% width.

I read somewhere, that the TinyMce-Editor takes the size of the area_field, so I tried this:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :cols =>10, :rows => 50, class: "tinymce" %>
```

The height changes according to the rows value, but the width stays fullscreen. I implented tinymce in rails with this tutorial: https://richonrails.com/articles/adding-tinymce-to-your-rails-application

I noticed, that in the tinymce.yml file, there are two lines, that mention fullscreen:

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen
```

But I couldn't figure out, what I need to change, to adjust the width of the editor. Any advices? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I added this to my blogposts:

```
<script>
 tinyMCE.init({
         // General options
         mode: "textareas",
         theme: "advanced",
         width: "300",
         height: "200",

         // Theme options
         theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
         theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
         theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
         theme_advanced_buttons4: "",
         theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
         theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
         theme_advanced_resizing: false,

     // Selector
         editor_selector: "tinymce",

 });
</script>
```

and then, my editor disappeared. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a sample code to adjust the width and nicely center the **tinymce**. Just set the width (here =400px) to the size you want.

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :content %><br />
   <div style="width: 400px">
      <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 3 %>
   </div>
</div>
```